# Windows phone reset while reset protection was on

Tags: reset

My brother got a windows phone from a friend who said to just reset it. The friend failed to inform that the phone had reset protection on. When he reset it, it locked up completely. does anybody know any ways around this?

Comment: Try with Windows Recovery Tool.

Comment: https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/windows-phone-reset-while-reset-protection-was-on

Answer (score 2):

`*#*#3646633#*#*` - Enter in engineering menu

`*#7780#` Restore factory settings

You can see the reference of these here: https://mobilespecs.net/phone/codes/Nokia/Nokia_Lumia_530.html